# C: Problem including a header file with CodeBlocks

Tags: c, codeblocks, header-files

I am having a problem with adding my header file "header.h" into my main file "main.c" (I am using CodeBlocks). The following is the minimal version where I can reproduce this error:

My main file looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "header.h"

struct _My_Struct_
{
  char* name_;
  int id_;
};

struct _Struct_List_
{
    struct _My_Struct_ struct_list[50];
};


int loadFILE(const char* file_name)
{
  FILE* file = fopen(file_name, "r");

  if (file == NULL)
    return 2;

  char line[10];
  fgets(line, sizeof(line), file);

  return 0;
}


int main()
{
  printf("Something_1\n");
  printHelloMessage();
  printf("Something_2\n");

  char person_string[] = "FirstName LastName [3]";
  char* name = strtok(person_string, "[");
  char* id_string = strtok(NULL, "]");

  printf("name= %s and id_string = %s\n", name, id_string);

  return 0;
}
```

My header file "header.h" looks like this:

```
#ifndef HEADER_H_INCLUDED
#define HEADER_H_INCLUDED

void printHelloMessage()
{
  printf("Hello!\n");
  printf("\n");
}

#endif // HEADER_H_INCLUDED
```

Running this problem leads to the error message

```
Process returned 32766 (0x7FFE)   execution time : 0.570 s
Press any key to continue.
```

I do not know what I am doing wrong, however, I noted that when I delete the struct part from main.c this works. Could you please tell me how to fix this?

Comment: Does not reproduce for me. Check that your files have been saved to disk and you are compiling and running the source code you think you are.

Comment: Show the full compiler output. Why do you believe it is the include which is causing it? Does it compile if you remove it (and the corresponding dependencies) ?

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Sorry for asking that but where can I find the full compiler output in CodeBlocks? (I am a total noob.)

Comment: I do not think thast this helps with the problem you describe, but you should drop the habit to habe non-header content (e.g. code) in an included header. The potential issue is hidden while you only have one code file, but later it is going to hurt you. Same applies to identifiers starting with `_`.

Comment: In order to prove that the code you are looking at is the one which actually gets compiled, I recommend to insert `#error This indeed gets compiled` into the code file and the header file. When you then build you should get confirmastion on those files. If not, your problem is as hinted by Eric.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone encounters a similar problem: In my case it was my antivirus (McAffe). Deactivating it solves the problem.